# Oracle SQL: The equivalent way to execute the following expression from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831736/postgresql-iterate-through-a-tables-rows-with-for-loop-retrieve-column-value-b) successfully showed how to use a an UPDATE SET and FROM clause together, to update an entire row of a specific column with a value derived from a different table.

When executing following expression in Oracle SQL:

```
UPDATE territory2_t
   SET total_sales_person = t.total_count
FROM (
   SELECT salesterritoryid, count(*) as total_count
   FROM salesperson_t
   group by salesterritoryid
) t 
WHERE territoryid = t.salesterritoryid;
```

Oracle states: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: In Oracle have a look at [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you can use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) to do the job:

```
merge into territory2_t
using (
       SELECT salesterritoryid, count(*) as total_count
       FROM salesperson_t
       group by salesterritoryid
      ) t
on (territoryid = t.salesterritoryid)
when matched then
    update SET total_sales_person = t.total_count
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `MERGE` (in Oracle and most other DB systems - those that implement the `MERGE` statement from the SQL Standard). `MERGE` is the preferred solution in most cases.

There is a misconception that this cannot be done with an `UPDATE` statement in Oracle. I show below how it **can** be done - not to encourage its use (`MERGE` is better), but to show that `UPDATE` can be used as well. This is the transformation of the Postgre SQL the OP solicited in the original post.

```
update ( select t2.total_sales_person, t.total_count
          from   territory2_t t2 inner join
                 ( select salesterritoryid, count(*) as total_count
                   from   salesperson_t
                   group by salesterritoryid
                 ) t
                 on t2.territoryid = t.salesterritoryid
       )
set total_sales_person = total_count;
```